# How do I join two tables with the newest record from table 2 that is older than a date for each record in table 1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

OK - not the clearest title. To explain better, I have the following table showing any occurrence of a Blue Screen of Death for any machine on my network. This query:

```
SELECT [ID]
      ,[ServiceTag]
      ,[BSOD]
FROM [ITDashboard].[dbo].[tl_login_BSOD]
```

gives the following:

[image]

Where the ServiceTag is the Service Tag of each machine and BSOD is the timestamp of when the Blue Screen occurred.

I have another table which logs various data (including the Windows build number). Each time the build number is changed (or some other fields I'm interested in) a new row is written to the database.

I can use this to find out the windows build of the machines on my network by selecting the record with the newest timestamp for each machine like this:

```
Select w1.machineName
      ,w1.timestamp
      ,w1.WindowsBuildNo
From [ITDashboard].[dbo].[tl_login_whom] As w1
Inner Join (
    Select machineName
          ,max(timestamp) as [timestamp]
    From [ITDashboard].[dbo].[tl_login_whom]
    Group By machineName) As [q]
On w1.machineName = q.machineName
And w1.timestamp = q.timestamp
```

Which returns this:

[image]

(MachineName and ServiceTag are interchangeable as we use the ServiceTags as the machine names.)

I want to write a query that brings back the first table, but also shows the Windows Build number **at the point when the Blue Screen occurred**.

I am almost there with the following query:

```
SELECT [ID]
          ,[ServiceTag]
          ,[BSOD],
          WindowsBuildNo
      FROM [ITDashboard].[dbo].[tl_login_BSOD] b
      JOIN (
          Select w1.machineName
                ,w1.timestamp
                ,w1.WindowsBuildNo
            From [ITDashboard].[dbo].[tl_login_whom] As w1
            Inner Join (
                Select machineName
                      ,max(timestamp) as [timestamp]
                From [ITDashboard].[dbo].[tl_login_whom]
                Group By machineName) As [q]
            On w1.machineName = q.machineName
            And w1.timestamp = q.timestamp
      ) w on w.machineName = b.serviceTag
```

but this brings back the newest build number every time. i.e. if a laptop bluescreened a month ago whilst on the older build number, but it is now on the newer build, the newer build is always shown.

What I need to bring back from the second query is the most recent record that is **older than the BSOD timestamp for the corresponding ServiceTag / MachineName**.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Please provide sample data for your tables as text (not as images) or, even better, as `INSERT` statements. Then, based on that sample data show us how the final result should look like. Also, add a tag with the version of SQL Server that you use.

Answer (score 1):

I figure BSOD means Windows machines, so also SQL Server.  You could use a CTE utilizing ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITION BY to re-align the table which contains changes to the Windows builds.

```
WITH _BuildTable AS (
SELECT MachineName
, WindowsBuild
, Timestamp
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineName ORDER BY Timestamp ASC) [RowNum]
FROM build_log_table
WHERE some_flag_column = "build has changed code"
)
, _BuildChanges AS (
SELECT BT1.MachineName
, BT1.WindowsBuild [BuildComing_From]
, BT2.WindowsBuild [BuildGoing_To]
, BT1.Timestamp [BuildTimeStart]
, CASE (WHEN BT2.TimeStamp IS NULL THEN '20500101' ELSE BT2.TimeStamp END)[BuildTimeEnd]
FROM _BuildTable AS BT1
LEFT JOIN _BuildTable AS BT2 ON BT1.MachineName = BT2.MachineName
AND BT1.RowNum = BT2.RowNum - 1
)

SELECT BC.MachineName
, BC.OldBuild [BSOD_Build]
, BC.Timestamp
, BC.[BuildTImeStart]
, BC.[BuildTImeEnd]
, BSOD.ID
, BSOD.ServiceTag
, BSOD.[BSOD] [TimeStamp]
FROM BSOD_log_table AS BSOD
LEFT JOIN _BuildChanges AS BC ON BSOD.ServiceTag = BC.MachineName
AND BSOD.[TimeStamp] > [BuildTImeStart] AND BSOD.[TimeStamp] < [BuildTImeEnd]
```

I'm thinking the build change logging table has a column that indicates the type of operation the row represents.  If not, the queries should still work, but you'll need to add a DISTINCT (BC.MachineName) to the final query because there will be extra rows for operations not related to changing the build.

Additionally, you'll have to handle the special case where a machine has never had a build change, and where a BSOD is happening on the current build.  That's the purpose of the CASE statement in _BuildChanges.